# Send parameter from Spring MVC controller to jsp code

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, controller

I'm trying to send the variable average review from controller to view and show a number of stars equal with average review.

The problem is that I don't know how to loop through received variable and java code doesn't recognize that variable. I tried with a foreach from JSTL, but there is no list of objects; I want a classic for loop.

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewProductDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
int productID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
// irrelevant code goes here
 double averageReview= reviewDAO.getAverageReview(productID);
 modelAndView.addObject("averageReview",averageReview);
 return modelAndView;
 }
```

This is my view page, where I tried to loop:

```
  <p>
      <c:set var = "averageReview" scope = "session" value ="${averageReview}"/>
      <% for(int i=0;i< ${averageReview}; i++){ %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      <% } %>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
  <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "0" end = "${averageReview}">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
  </c:forEach>
```